# Can't browse to my EC2 Instance

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, cloud

I've just (about 1 hour ago) associated an **Elastic IP** to my instance at Amazon **EC2**. If I SSH into my instance and type `lynx localhost` I can see that apache is responsive because I see the **It works** page.

However, If I browse into my instance (both via the IP itself *and* via the public DNS Amazon has created for me), I get **Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to**.. bla bla...

Should I wait some more time (in case it's due to some DNS thing) or does this indicate something is wrong?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** When I ssh into my instance, I use the full IP address and it works... (the Elastic IP I mean).

Comment: Are you trying to browse to the public IP & public DNS set up when you created the instance?

Comment: I'm trying to browse to the Elastic IP directly *and* also via the public DNS.. Neither of those works...

Comment: Did you config the firewall to let HTTP port open?

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida what IP address are you using to ssh in? The elastic IP?

Comment: @ismaelga no I had not. Now I did and it works. Write an answer so that you can receive the award points.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You must config the firewall to open the HTTP port.

To be more specific, for AWS this is done via Security Groups. You should create one with the ports you need opened. In most cases that's the por 80 for TCP.

You can see how to achieve this on the documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

Comment: thx Ismael. It has been a puzzle for me.

Comment: This doesn't tell anyone what to do to fix it.

Comment: 1. Log in to AWS and click `Security Groups` on the left under `Network & Security`
2. Select your group from the list of security groups in the top panel
3. Click the `Inbound` tab in the panel on the bottom and click the button labeled `Edit`
4. Click the `Add Rule` button
5. Apply the following settings in the new rule:
Type: `Custom TCP Rule`
Port Range: `80`
Source: `Anywhere`

Comment: Confirmed. Was not able to get traffic going to the IP address, but could see from within Links on the machine. Clicked Security Groups and saw that ONLY SSH port was open. Clicked to add a rule and voila, working perfectly.

Answer (score 17):

- First identify the security group of the Ec2 instance.

  - Next click on the security groups link in the bottom left nav.
  - Select the security group under which this EC2 instance lies,
    and add Inbound rules by specifying the port or a custom port range.

Comment: This fixed my issue running an EX2 under Ubuntu 13.10, thank you, +1

Comment: This should be the selected answer. Although it probably should give advice on ports or what rules to add etc.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you using Centos (and perhaps other linux distibutions), you need to make sure that its FW (iptables) allows for port 80 or any other port you want.

See [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/fedora-redhat-centos-5-6-disable-firewall/) on how to completely disable it (for testing purposes only!).
And [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-fedorta-linux-iptables-firewall-configuration-tutorial/) for specific rules